# M-x shell truncates commands to 4096 characters

Tags: shell, comint

Using M-x shell, I have encountered a problem with commandlines being truncated to 4095 characters.

Steps to reproduce:

1. `perl -e 'print "0" x 5000 . "\n"'`
2. Select output for next command
3. `echo <5000 zeros> > /tmp/emacs_5000`

Expected behaviour:

`wc /tmp/emacs_5000` should return

`1    1 5001 /tmp`

Current behaviour:

4090 zeros are output into the shell.

Interpretation: only the first 4095 characters (4090 output + 'echo ') are passed to the shell process.

Is my interpretation correct?

Is the a way to fix it?

Comment: This sounds like `process-connection-type` specifying a pty.  When terminal input is subject to the line discipline provided for TTYs by the OS, it may impose a maximum line size (4096 chars in GNU/Linux, for example) with larger lines being truncated.  I'm not sure whether *not* using a pty is any kind of issue for `M-x shell`, but see whether `M-: (setq process-connection-type nil)` before starting the shell changes things.

Comment: n.b. I'm guessing a bit, because I can't replicate the problem with the given recipe; but I've encountered this kind of issue in other situations.

Comment: I believe https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=6149#19 also describes this problem.

Comment: (The latter recipe I can reproduce in both 26.3 and 27.0.90; I'm not sure why I couldn't replicate the issue with your recipe).